# Using Django Template With tag name of tag is used instead of variable

Tags: django, templates

When query_dict['ident'] = 'foobargag' and query_dict['Q1'] = '2'

```
{% with ident=q.ident %}
<p>ident = {{ident}}</p>
<p>query_dict.ident = {{query_dict.ident}}</p>
```

I get:
ident = Q1
query_dict.ident = foobargag
(I should note that query_dict is actually a plain dict and that the example has been simplified. My actual use case does not have ident in the dict; it is there only to demonstrate what is happening.)

I expected to see the value '2'. Is it possible to dereference ident to get what I want?

Thanks, Ken

Comment: You should try to make an [mcve]

Comment: Well, how do you expect to see value as '2'? query_dict.ident = foobargag is what you will get as ident is the key belonging to query_dict. I understand what you are trying to do here, but I do not think it will work here